# Interactive command line user interfaces in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

The Command `npm init`, ask a series of questions and gets those answer and write it in a file?

How can I create a similar command line utility in node?

Is there any packages available?

Some Examples would be much helpful for me.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [inquirier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer) package should meet your needs. Have a look at the examples they provide [here](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/tree/master/examples) on github

Comment: Thanks robocode.. Exactly what i was looking for.. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Vorpal.js](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal) is built on top of Inquirer.js, and provides an interactive CLI, with an easy API for adding commands, which seems to be what you are looking for.

Implementing is easy:

```
var vorpal = require('vorpal')();

vorpal
  .delimiter('myapp$')
  .show();

vorpal
  .command('foo', 'Logs "bar".')
  .action(function(args, cb){
    this.log('bar');
    cb();
  });
```

Your app is now interactive:

```
$ node app.js
myapp$ foo
bar
myapp$
```

*Disclaimer: I wrote Vorpal, so if you have questions, ask away.*