# How do I configure options and run a specific npm script based on the option selected

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I am looking at how to configure options and to run an npm script based on the option selected at terminal

for example, I have a package.json file

```
{
"scripts": {
    "tests:mac": "export ENV=dev& testcafe \"chrome --start-fullscreen\" automation_suite/",
    "tests:windows": "set ENV=dev& testcafe \"chrome --start-fullscreen\" automation_suite/",
    "tests": ??????
   }
}
```

What should I write here `"tests:"`

My requirement is to run `npm run tests`
then it should give options on terminal like

```
OS:
windows <
mac
```

if I selected `windows` it should execute `tests:windows`

if I selected `mac` it should execute `tests:mac`

How to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need an interactive UI? Just type e.g. `npm run tests:windows`. Or use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-script-os.

Comment: Actually, I just gave a small example here, I wanted to know how to achieve this, as I have a lot of options to configure in my project.

Comment: Then see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/32735809/3001761

Answer (score 0):

Try ntl https://github.com/ruyadorno/ntl might be useful.
Still trying to find out a better option

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.